# Problems with CSS Positioning in gmail,

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble finding the problem with my code and gmail (webmail) strips down all the css.

The code works on most email providers, but not with gmail webmail.

Can someone help me find the solution?
Here is the code!

https://codeshare.io/5vN9Wl

Comment: The indexing etc. seems like a mess, but from what I could see, skimming through the code, you are missing some end tags etc. ? Idk if that could have some impact, but worth checking.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include all code relevant to the question in the question itself. Preferably as a [MCVE]. Note you can use the `{}` button in the editor to format text as code or use the `<>` button to create an interactive snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you would run your code trough the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/check) You'll notice a few things wrong which might help you to fix any layout issues you might have.

**A few issues currently:**

- Using non-existent declaration tags (leftmargin, marginwidth, offset etc.)
- Quotes missing `<td height=20>`instead of `<td height="20">`
- Wrongly inserted HTML `&nbsp;="">`
- Tags not closing correctly `<span style="color:#a2a2a2;" </span>`

Take a look at fixing the HTML errors using the W3C Validator, that might help you a long way.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0"
  style="margin: 0pt auto; padding: 0px; background:#F4F7FA;">
    <table id="main" width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
    bgcolor="#F4F7FA">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            <table class="innermain" cellpadding="0" width="580" cellspacing="0" border="0"
            bgcolor="#F4F7FA" align="center" style="margin:0 auto; table-layout: fixed;">
              <tbody>
                <!-- START of MAIL Content -->
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="4">
```

not having proper closing tags.